# Updating/Creating Additioanl .profile for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm trying to make my life easier by adding a PATH so that instead of having to type in `~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel` everytime into my terminal to access the `Laravel` installer menu I can just type in `laravel` to bring up the same Laravel installer commands. I already have a .profile file that is set up to point to MAMP Pro's PHP module so I'm unsure if I have to update it with an additional line or if I should be creating a new .profile page in a different directory to allow feel or this to happen.

File is located here: ~/ as .profile

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin:$PATH
```

Edit: I currently have composer residing in my ~/usr/bin/composer directory because when I put it inside of the ~/usr/local/bin/composer directory I cannot type composer commands it says they don't exist. I am running on a OS X Mavericks installation on my Mac. With composer in the directory it currently is in I am able to run composer commands. I have a .profile file that has the above path inside it pointing to Mamp's PHP installation. I'm wanting to be able to just type in "laravel" into my terminal to get the Laravel installation tool but instead of having to type in

~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel everytime so I saw on a video that you have to add a path but everytime I do it overwrites that one I already have.

Is there any additional ideas that pertain to the exporting situation.

Comment: `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin`

Comment: its already in there

Comment: well its in /usr/bin/composer because if I move it to local then when I run composer it doesn't work so I kept it in bin

Comment: What happens when you use composer and run it when it's in /usr/local/bin

Comment: You're running Mac OSX right?

Comment: Try `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

Comment: Make sure there is a file `composer` in /usr/local/bin

Comment: Well my composer directory is in the /usr/bin/composer because when I move it into the local then I can't run composer commands. However this is off topic of what I had asked.

Comment: composer shouldn't be a directory -- it should be a file residing in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Then why when I type in composer it says command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Remove your current composer.phar or composer file and run the two commands above.

If you're still getting command not found, something is wrong with your operating system.

Comment: Read the comment I wrote above.

Comment: I did you must've messed something up with your OS if the above answer does not work in which case you'd need to further debug which also means it's not a programming/development question but a problem with your filesystem.

Comment: This is a good answer however does not solve my initial question about exporting paths. Because I have the one .profile file with the path to Mamp's php and I don't know where file to put this additional export path for Laravel at.